# How to tell if timestamp from Postgres in Java is null

Tags: java, postgresql

The code below is a snippet from a back-end REST service I have touched on. I'm wondering how to tell if a timestamp I'm getting is null. I've learned through trial and error that if the timestamp is null in the Postgres database that when I bring it into Java that if its null it will get instantiated as a new DateTime at the current time of operation. What can I do to check get and set nulls dynamically according to model data?

```
public List<SubscriptionEntityModel> getAllSubscriptions(PagingInfoDomainModel paging) throws Exception {
    Database db = new Database();

    String stmt = "{call sp_subscriptions_get_all(?, ?)}";

    if(AppConfig.data.isDebug) {
        logger.debug("Running database operation.. " + stmt);
    }

    CallableStatement sproc = db.dbEndpoint.prepareCall(stmt);
    sproc.setInt(1, paging.pageCurrent);
    sproc.setInt(2, paging.pageItemCount);

    ResultSet rs = sproc.executeQuery();

    List<SubscriptionEntityModel> subscriptions = new ArrayList<SubscriptionEntityModel>();
    while(rs.next()) {
        SubscriptionEntityModel subscription = new SubscriptionEntityModel();
        subscription.subscriptionId = rs.getInt("subscription_id");
        subscription.name = rs.getString("name");
        subscription.emailAddress = rs.getString("email_address");
        subscription.phoneNumber = rs.getString("phone_number");
        subscription.organizationId = rs.getInt("organization_id");

        subscription.createdAt = new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("created_at"));
        subscription.expiredAt = new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("expired_at"));

        subscriptions.add(subscription);
    }

    sproc.close();
    db.destroy();

    return subscriptions;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out ResultSet#wasNull

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()

> Reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL NULL.

Hence you can use it after `rs.getTimestamp()` to check if the value read was SQL NULL, but note that ResultSet#getTimestamp already returns a null reference if that was the case.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(int)

> the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null

The problem you're facing is that when you pass a null reference to the constructor of DateTime, it will be interpreted as *now*.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> java.sql.Timestamp getTimestamp(String columnLabel) throws SQLException;
> ```

will return `null` if the SQL field is `NULL`.

The problem is the way you instantiate your `DateTime` object.
With JodaTime (I give this example as you don't specify the used library), executing the following code creates indeed a `DateTime` instance with the actual date time :

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = null;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp);
```

So to solve your problem, what you could do is checking the returned value by the resultset.
If it is not `null`, use it to create the `DateTime` object.
Otherwise don't use it and leave to `null`the `DateTime` field of the `SubscriptionEntityModel` you are setting properties.

So instead of doing :

```
subscription.createdAt = new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("created_at"));
```

You should do :

```
 java.sql.Timestamp createdAt = rs.getTimestamp("created_at");
 if (createdAt != null){
   subscription.expiredAt = new DateTime(createdAt);
 }
```

Comment: this was very helpful! thank you very much for helping me understand the problem.